# Horizontally stack two Nx1 matrices

Tags: calc

In Calc I have two bidimensional, Nx1 matrices

```
' [1 2 3] RET v t RET
```

if I use the `|` command I get a 2Nx1 matrix (let's say a vertical stack)
and of course i could

```
' [1 2 3] RET RET | vt
```

to get what I want but I have already the Nx1 matrices and I wonder if there is a command to avoid transposing the individual matrices, stacking and eventually transposing another time...

Tia

Comment: Is your intended result an Nx2 matrix?

Comment: @Juancho Yes: Nx2

Comment: So you actually want to construct `'{{11,12},{21,22},{31,32}}` from `{11,21,31}` and `{12,22,32}`. Please write that in your question. Both your current recipes do not work.

Comment: One of your problems is that you start off with vectors and not with matrices. Use `'{{11 21 31}} RET '{{12 22 32}} RET | vt` instead.